# Couchbase Lite on Android L

Tags: android, couchbase, android-5.0-lollipop, couchbase-lite

After updating to Android L, I got errors like this, though before (on Android 4.4 Nexus 7 2013) everything was fine:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "mConnectionPtr" in class "Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection;" or its superclasses
        at com.couchbase.touchdb.TDCollateJSON.nativeRegisterCustomCollators(Native Method)
        at com.couchbase.touchdb.TDCollateJSON.registerCustomCollators(TDCollateJSON.java:11)
        at com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidSQLiteStorageEngine.open(AndroidSQLiteStorageEngine.java:46)
        at com.couchbase.lite.Database.open(Database.java:909)
        at com.couchbase.lite.Manager.getDatabase(Manager.java:228)
        at com.explain.messenger.model.utils.CBHelper.init(CBHelper.java:55)
```

Exeption occures after trying to create database :

```
 manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(appContext),
                Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
 Database db = manager.getDatabase("db_name"); // exception here
```

does anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: found this issue on GitHub : 
[link](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/373)
hope they will solve it soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was fixed.
Use this build from master
[CouchBase Lite - build 463](http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/lite/couchbase-lite-android/0.0.0-463/)

Or just wait new version 1.0.3 to be released.

### Gradle

```
compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:0.0.0-463'
```

### Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.couchbase.lite</groupId>
  <artifactId>couchbase-lite-android</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0-463</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to [Tleyden](https://github.com/tleyden)

Comment: Version released with this bug fixed !! Version 1.0.3. http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/release-notes/Android/index.html The bug in question is the #373 (https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/issues/373)